# Insert if exists but change value

Tags: mysql

I have the following DB and i'm trying to make a querie that insert some values but if there is duplicate values on column link AND price is different i want to set newPrice to 1. 
I can't use unique key because i need to keep all the records to track prices.

id : primary key, AI 
name : varchar 
link : varchar 
price : int 
newPrice : bool default value 0

```
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+
| id |   name  |    link   |   price   | newPrice|
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+
|  1 |  test   | google.com|     10    |    0    |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+
|  2 |  test2  | google.fr |     15    |    0    |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+
|  3 |  test3  | google.it |     12    |    0    |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

For example :

```
insert into dbname(name,link,price) VALUES (test3, google.it, 12)
```

This querie will insert a new record with newPrice to 0

```
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+
|  4 |  test3  | google.it |     12    |    0    |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

example 2 :

```
insert into dbname(name,link,price) VALUES (test3, google.it, 19)
```

this querie will insert a new record but as i already have a record with google.it in link column and the price is different i need to set newPrice to 1.

```
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+
|  5 |  test3  | google.it |     19    |    1    |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

Today i am doing it with my PHP script but it make a lot of time to do it all.
I made a first select to know if a record is already in the DB, if rowcount > 0 i insert with newPrice at 1 else newPrice 0.
I have ~200K data a day to manage and it actually takes a lot of time to do so i am trying to better it.

Can i make it in one querie or should i use a custom SQL function or something else ?

Thank you !

Comment: Why can't you create a unique key on the `name` column? Your explanation doesn't make sense.

Comment: because the same name can be on different link

Answer (score 0):

```sql
INSERT INTO tablename (name, link, price, newPrice) 
SELECT 'test3', 
       'google.it', 
       12,
       EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                FROM tablename
                WHERE (name, link) = ('test3', 'google.it')
                  AND price <> 12 )
;
```